# emacs ido-find-file default file is current line

Tags: emacs

Can I start with `Find file: /currentpath/` in the minibuffer when I do `M-x ido-find-file`?

When I run `M-x ido-find-file` (or `C-x C-f` in my setup), emacs uses the current line as the default file. It shows `Find file: /currentpath/currentlineinbuffer` in the minibuffer. So the first thing I have to do is delete that default file (e.g., using `ESC backspace`).

I know about `C-x C-f C-f` to go back to regular find-file behavior, but I prefer to use ido-find-file except for this issue.

Comment: you can use the `backticks` to help the readability of your post

Comment: thanks. I added some backticks. it's my first post.

Comment: I know! I had the pleasure of reviewing your first post (you gain that ability once you have enough reputation). Looks much better :)

Comment: The value of variable `ido-use-filename-at-point` should be `nil` for required behavior. Remove string `(setq ido-use-filename-at-point 't)`(or something like this) from your config or setup `(setq ido-use-filename-at-point nil)` at the end of the config.

Comment: This will be helpful.  Once you hit C-x C-f and see the location type //.  This will take you to root location.

Comment: Thanks. artscan's suggestion changed the behavior the way I wanted. Could you point me to the best place for the ido docs? Or should I have just looked in ido.el?

Comment: Maybe it helps you `(customize-group 'ido)` http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Ido http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings

Comment: thanks. is there some way for me to accept artscan's comment as the answer?

Comment: There is only one way. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of variable ido-use-filename-at-point should be nil for required behavior. Remove string

```
(setq ido-use-filename-at-point 't)
```

(or something like this) from your config or setup

```
(setq ido-use-filename-at-point nil)
```

at the end of the config.